# multiplication by $Q$ preserves length. So $||Qx|| = ||x||$ for any $x$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $Q$ be a matrix with orthonormal columns. Right away I know that $Q^TQ = QQ^T = I$. I want to show that multiplication by $Q$ preserves length. So $||Qx|| = ||x||$ for any $x$. But how do I go about showing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:
$$
\|Qx\|^2=(Qx)^T(Qx)=(x^TQ^T)(Qx)
$$

Comment: okay from here how do I get $||x||$ $(x^tQ^T(Qx) = (xQ)^T(Qx) $??

Comment: @tshelton Apply $Q^TQ=I$.

Comment: $(x^TQ^T)(Qx) = (Q^TQ)(x^Tx) = Ix=x$??

Comment: @tshelton No: $(x^TQ^T)(Qx)=x^T(Q^TQ)x=x^TIx=x^Tx=\|x\|^2$.

Comment: then $||x||^2=||x||$?

Comment: @tshelton Why? We proved $\|Qx\|^2=\|x\|^2$.

Comment: so $||Qx||^2=||x||^2$ is equivalent $||Qx||=||x||$?

Comment: @tshelton Of course it is, because $\|v\|\ge0$ for every $v$.

Comment: I am looking for $||Qx|| = ||x||$